# Optimizing full text search process in databases nowdays

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, full-text-search, algolia

I need to store millions of records (with several text fields) in a database and to make full text search queries on them (hopefully as fast as possible).
What are the best alternatives and best practices for this case?
Which DB should I use? currently Im reading about elasticsearch, mongo and algolia...
Is there something to do in order to optimize the process besides Indexing?
Thanks :)

Comment: We cant answer that question, we need more inforamtion: What s you need to search, is it text only? amount of users, do you need replicate data on different cloud center...Size of document ects...Without more information, if you are looking for full text, es is a must.